# Dataframe questions about read excel

Tags: python, pandas

I can´t see the result...
My result is `0` and it should be `824`

```py
import pandas as pd

apple = r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\AAPL.xlsx'

data = pd.read_excel(apple)
dateindextime = data.set_index("timestamp")

rango = dateindextime.loc["2011-08-20":"2008-05-15"]
print(len(rango))
```

If I do

```py
print(rango)
```

output:

```
Empty DataFrame Columns: [open, high, low, close, adjusted_close, volume] Index: []
```

Comment: If I print(rango)   output=  Empty DataFrame
Columns: [open, high, low, close, adjusted_close, volume]
Index: []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda hard to tell without the AAPL.xlsx dataset, but I'm guessing you will need to convert the "timestamp" column to a datetime object first [using pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). From there you would slice on the datetime object vs slicing on a string, which is what you were doing below. If you posted the AAPL.xlsx dataset, I could dig deeper.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

apple = r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\AAPL.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(apple) 
data["datetime_timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(data["timestamp"], infer_datetime_format=True)
dateindextime = data.set_index("datetime_timestamp")
ti = datetime.date(2008,5,15)
tf = datetime.date(2011,8,20)
rango = dateindextime.loc[ti:tf] 
print(len(rango))
```